# Why does the graph form not finish displaying all its UI, in my VB.net window forms app?

Tags: vb.net

When my app boots, the main form's load event calls start_graph_thread(), which starts the execloop run_graph_management() for a worker form that graphs.  run_graph_management() waits for a signal to process requests to do things like resize the worker form.

The problem is that at boot the worker form displays, but doesn't completely show all it's UI, and then doesn't respond to resizing.  The main form is ok and I can move and resize it.

Mouse shows hourglass when hovering over graph form.

```
Public Class Antenna_Window_Template

. . .


' This is called when main window loads at boot-time.
Public Sub start_graph_thread()
    Me.graph_Thread = New Thread(Sub() Me.run_graph_management())
    Me.graph_Thread.Start()
End Sub

sub run_graph_management()
    static dim I_color as Color, Q_color as Color
    ' Signal graph management thread:
    signal_resize += 1
    antenna_graph_interface(antenna_window_index).graph_action_request_ManualResetEvent.Set()

    thread.Sleep(0)

    ' Threads EXEC LOOP:
    Do
        ' Wait for communication thread to hand-off block of samples for this antenna, or config signal from Main UI :
        ''''''''''''''   A W A I T   S I G N A L   '''''''''''''''
        ' Check for signals from other threads:
        antenna_graph_interface(antenna_window_index).graph_action_request_ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()       ' await signal
        antenna_graph_interface(antenna_window_index).graph_action_request_ManualResetEvent.Reset()     ' reset signal
        ' Another thread just signalled this graph thread to do something.  Go find out what:

        if signal_resize <> prev_signal_resize                                       ''''''''''''''''   R E - S I Z E   ''''''''''''''''
            prev_signal_resize = signal_resize

            ' Resize chart UI control:
            tad_x = 20
            tad_y = 20
            Me.TabControl_antenna_window.Width = Me.Width - 5
            Me.Chart_antenna_window.width = Me.TabControl_antenna_window.Width - tad_x

            Me.TabControl_antenna_window.Height = Me.Height - 40
            Me.Chart_antenna_window.height = Me.TabControl_antenna_window.Height - Me.Chart_antenna_window.Top - tad_y
        End If

        ' . . .  several other flags are checked

        loops += 1

        Application.DoEvents()    ' DoEvents method does not call the Thread.Sleep method.
    Loop
End sub
```

Comment: You don't work with controls on any thread but the UI thread. If you're seeing issues with your UI, that would be why. You can work with the data you need to display in a secondary thread but then, when you need to actually modify the controls (including displaying data) you need to marshal back to the UI thread. You've got some reading to do, I think.

Comment: I totally understand.  Just did some deep thinking at the gym this morning and realize the "error of my ways."  jmcihinney, thanks so much for that corroboration.  I shall post my solution after I get it working today.